# The order of a differential operator on a manifold is well-defined

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

In [these notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~palbin/Math524.Spring2012/LectureNotesMay1.pdf), the author defines a differential operator of order at most $n$ on a manifold $M$ as an element of $\operatorname{Diff}^n(M) := \operatorname{span}_{0\leq j \leq n} (C^\infty(M;TM))^j.$ Then, he states the following:

> Notice that the fact that the degree
>   of a differential operator is well-defined comes from the fact that the commutator
>   of two vector fields is again a vector field.

Why is this remark even needed? Did we not define $\operatorname{Diff}^n(M)$ in a coordinate-independent way? Does this refer to his earlier, coordinate-dependent "definition"? If so, how does this come from the fact that the commutator of two vector fields is a vector field?